# Meteor use MongoDB-collection with array of objects that already exists

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I made a python script that reads a file and creates a new mongoDB collection.
The collection is as follows, when I print one document of the collection in python:

```
{'_id': '5b5b0a55ca902423007413b9',
 'employee': 'John Doe',
 'schedule': [{'date': '08/11/2018', 'project': 'Drawing'},

                                     ... 

               {'date': '05/06/2018', 'project': 'Teaching'}
             ]
}
```

I made a collection in meteor using this code:

```
Planning = new Meteor.Collection("Planning");
```

Planning is also the name I gave the collection in python.
Now when I run this code in Meteor (server side):

```
Meteor.methods({
    getFullPlanning: function(){
        var one = Planning.find({ employee: 'John Doe'});
        console.log(one.employee);  
    }
});
```

This piece of code logs undefined, but there is an employee with that name in my collection. What am I doing wrong in Meteor?

But this does work:

```
Planning.find().count() // = 53 which is correct!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Meteor docs](https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection-find):

> `find` returns a cursor. It does not immediately access the database or return documents. Cursors provide `fetch` to return all matching documents, `map` and `forEach` to iterate over all matching documents, and `observe` and `observeChanges` to register callbacks when the set of matching documents changes.

Your variable, `one`, is a cursor, and not the document. If you're only looking for a single document, you can call `Planning.findOne({ employee: 'John Doe' })` which will return a single document, or undefined if no matches were found. You can also call `Planning.find({ employee: 'John Doe' }).fetch()`.